# How can I fix my toilet valve so I can stop jiggling the handle after flushing?

Tags: toilet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my toilet intermittently run continually?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/506/why-does-my-toilet-intermittently-run-continually)

Clearly the valve plunger (?) isn't seating correctly, but I don't know what to do about it.  If I flush, wait 2 seconds, jiggle the handle, then everything is fine.  Otherwise, the water will run all day.

Can I put vaseline around the edge of the hole in the tank?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can purchase a new flapper valve if you can find one of the same model, or my preference is to replace the entire guts of the toilet if they are more than 5 or so years old.  Kits and/or parts are easy to find at your local HI store and it's one of the easier plumbing jobs out there (though notoriously dirty).

Just be sure you follow the first rule of toilet repair: do not over tighten or use force.  The porcelain can take a lot of compression, but if anything is pushed to expand, it will crack easily and you're left with buying a new toilet, replacing the wax seal, and possibly the supply line if your existing one isn't flexible.

Comment: I did replace the flapper valve.  This is with the new valve.

Comment: @Michael, in that case, the plastic seat of the valve may not be fitting well or something is misaligned.  If you don't feel any rough edges, watch how the flapper falls with the lid off during a flush and see how it's shifting when you jiggle it.

Comment: And note from tester's comment that this could be a lot of other issues beyond the flapper valve.

Comment: Make sure the chain between the lever and flapper isn't kinked or too short. Also make sure it's not too long or it can drop under the flapper preventing a proper seal.

Comment: @billoreid It was the chain! but it wasn't too short or kinked. It was too long, and the extra piece was falling into the drain and the flapper valve was coming down on top of it, preventing a tight seal.