# How can I stop a running toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I have a really weird issue: my toilet is running water, but it's not in the tank. It seems like there's a neverending small flow of water entering the bowl of the toilet from the left side of the bowl. How can I stop this "leak?"

Comment: See also [why does my toilet intermittently run continually](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/506/why-does-my-toilet-intermittently-run-continually)

Answer (score 13):

When you can avoid using the toilet for a bit, put a little food coloring in the tank. If the water in the bowl changes color after an hour or so, the flapper isn't sealing properly and should be replaced. If the water is still clear but you see a flow of water, the fill valve isn't fully closing and water is entering via the line attached to the overflow tube. Typically, if I go through the trouble of replacing either of these, I replace the entire innards of the toilet.

Comment: Great answer. Also, flapper valves IMHO are the problem 9/10 times...